# How to show generated password in list

Tags: android, listview

```
btnGenerateNums.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tvGeneratedNums.setText("");
            tvResultInTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvResultInListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mList.clear();
            if(isValid())
                {
                tvResultInTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvResultInListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                RandomNumGenerator mRandomNumGen = new RandomNumGenerator(start,end);
                for(int i=0;i<=end-start;i++)
                         {

                    int k = mRandomNumGen.generateNewRandom(i);

                    mList.add(k);

                }
                if(tvGeneratedNums.getText().toString().endsWith(","))
                {
                    tvGeneratedNums.setText(tvGeneratedNums.getText().toString().substring(0, tvGeneratedNums.getText().toString().length()-1));
                }

            }
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList);
            lvGeneratedNums.setAdapter(mAdapter);


            }
    });
```

I want to show my generated password into list view so I write this but this give me only one number like this

3

5

10

6

9

8

But what I want is

3  5  10  6  9  8

8 10  6  9  3  5

5  10  9  8  3  6

9  5  6  10  3  8

And so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need loop your generate more number like what you want, here some code:

```
btnGenerateNums.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tvGeneratedNums.setText("");
        tvResultInTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvResultInListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mList.clear();

        if(isValid())
            {
            tvResultInTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvResultInListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            RandomNumGenerator mRandomNumGen = new RandomNumGenerator(start,end);
            for(int i=0;i<=end-start;i++) {
                String randPass = "";
                for(int j=0;j<=5;j++) {
                    int ch = mRandomNumGen.generateNewRandom(i);
                    randPass += " " +String.valueOf(ch);
                }
                mList.add(randPass);
            }
            if(tvGeneratedNums.getText().toString().endsWith(","))
            {
                tvGeneratedNums.setText(tvGeneratedNums.getText().toString().substring(0, tvGeneratedNums.getText().toString().length()-1));
            }

        }
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList);
        lvGeneratedNums.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        }
});
```

with mList is List<String>;, i dont test this code, just give you an options.

Comment: Its show me one error "There is no Applicable method to'(Java.Lang.String)'"

Comment: I just uploded my code to mediafire can you please take a look and help me please Somy

Comment: First thanks for your help its work but i have a question how can i random this list sorry for my bad english

Comment: Now Happy i answered it !